# How can I use DataContext class to establish a connection to Oracle Database?

Tags: linq, orm, datacontext, oracle9i

Is it possible to use the DataContext class to connect to an Oracle DB?

I am reading some examples on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx)

I need an example where the context is used to connect to Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataContext`s are specific to LINQ-to-SQL and thus SQL Server. If you want an ORM for Oracle, you need to look at alternatives like the Microsoft Entity Framework or NHibernate.